# deleting boost archive object also deletes stream associated to it?

Tags: c++, boost, delete-operator, ofstream

In my code, I have to keep a persistent boost::oarchive object to write. So I have a writer class which keeps pointers of ostream and boost::oarchive pointers say -

`ofstream *fs = new ofstream();`

`boost::archive::binary_oarchive *afs = new boost::archive::binary_oarchive( *fs );`

I am having issues while destructing them. Here is what I do in my clear function to release the objects -

`delete fs;`

`delete afs;`   #valigrind throws invalid read

Valgrind throws an invalid read error while destructing 'afs' here - is 'delete fs' *not* required? Does deleting the boost object sufficient to release ofstream object as well?

Comment: Is `boost::oarchive` a real type?  Please edit your question to provide a [mcve] if possible.

Comment: Sorry, I was referring to binary_oarchive. I have edited the question.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you’re allocating these objects with `new`?

Comment: So I have an API to write out information which is called (multiple times) in between the full flow and later I figured out that making an archive then and there inside the API prints out boost serialization header every time which made problems for the reader later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The archive probably wants to flush something to file stream before self destruction, but you already closed the file stream.

**So, delete archive first, then delete your ofstream.**

In most cases, it is safe to destruct dependent objects in the reverse order of their construction.